# how to add custom block field data in db from shipping method page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]

I have made block below the shipping method selection block in which I have 2 fields now I want to save the data in database. on which file c I can get the custom field values.

Comment: 1. Which extension use and 2. you want to value insert database and get value admin panel???

Comment: I want to insert the value in db

Comment: https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-additional-shipping-block

Comment: i have many file change you connect me other platform. i will provide full module...

Comment: ok how can we get connect I need this module urgently. mustafabaltii786@gmail.com here is my email address u can mail me

Comment: in my profile i have added skype link.